How can I handle error when using zod and server actions in my next js form?
I am learning nextjs 14 (AppRoute). I want to validate a form using zod in my nextjs project. Under the each form input I want to show error's from zod and if server action failed to insert values(formData) to server or any other error occured in server I want to render that error on top of my form.
This is my form component...
import { registerUser } from "@/app/actions";

export default function RegistrationForm() {
  return (
    <form className='login-form' action={registerUser}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor='fname'>First Name</label>
        <input type='text' name='firstName' id='fname' />
        {/* if error occured in firstName validation ------> show error about firstName */}
      </div>

      <div>
        <label htmlFor='lname'>Last Name</label>
        <input type='text' name='lastName' id='lname' />
        {/* if error occured in lastName validation ------> show error about lasstName */}
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor='email'>Email Address</label>
        <input type='email' name='email' id='email' />
        {/* if error occured in email validation ------> show error about email */}
      </div>

      <div>
        <label htmlFor='password'>Password</label>
        <input type='password' name='password' id='password' />
        {/* if error occured in password validation ------> show error about password */}
      </div>

      <button
        type='submit'
        className='bg-[#eb4a36] py-3 rounded-md text-white w-full mt-4'
      >
        Create Account
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}


this is server action...
"use server";

import { createUser } from "@/db/queries";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

async function registerUser(formData) {
  try {
    const user = Object.fromEntries(formData);
    const created = await createUser(user);
  } catch (error) {
    throw error.message;
  }

  if (created) {
    redirect("/login");
  }
}

export { registerUser };

createUser function to insert formData into mongoDB
async function createUser(user) {
  try {
    await connectMongo();
    return await userModel.create(user);
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}

export {createUser}

So I need help to integrate zod validation and handle error for both client and server side in my project.

what you have tried so far with zod ?

no it;s my first time.... I can implement zod with required schemas but I can't handle error's that returned from zod also from server actions together.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78417007/nextjs-14-server-side-actions-with-shadcn-form/78417172#78417172
you can check this

Yeah that's right.I am ok with client side validation but I want also handle server side error from server action in the same form component(error that comes from server will render top of the form)

After calling server action, not just throw error, reformat and set it into state as well, like link above.
